# jQuery datatables: how to stop it from adding 'odd' or 'even' to the class name

Tags: jquery, datatables

This is all I'm using for datatable...

```
$("#resultsTable").dataTable({
    dom:'Blfrtip',
    buttons: [
       'excelHtml5',
       'csvHtml5',
       'pdfHtml5'
    ],

    "fnPreDrawCallback":function(){
        $("#resultsTable").hide();
        //alert("Pre Draw");
    },
    "fnDrawCallback":function(){
        $("#resultsTable").show();
        //alert("Draw");
    },
    "fnInitComplete":function(){
        //alert("Complete");
    }
});
```

But it adds 'odd' or 'even' to the class name of each row it seems, which I do *not* want. How can I get it to leave the class names alone?

Comment: Couldn't you just do a `$("#resultsTable tr").removeClass( "odd even" )`?

Comment: Why are the extra classes bothering you in the first place?

Comment: Here is how btw : https://datatables.net/reference/option/stripeClasses

Comment: Thanks for helping me find that. stripeClasses was not on my radar.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to remove stripe classes globally, set the default options:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.ext.classes, {
  sStripeEven: '', sStripeOdd: ''
});
```

If you want to disable the classes during initialization:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "stripeClasses": []
} );
```

If you want to disable them on the table directly via data attributes:

```
<table data-stripe-classes="[]">
</table>
```

Comment: I was looking high and low. Disabling during initialization is exactly what I needed to fake it out. I wanted stripes displayed before sorting and match stripes after sorting. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I added `"stripeClasses": []`, but it didn't have any effect. I had to remove "table-striped" in the list of classes in the table element used to create this data table. For instance, if you have a list of classes like this:

```
<table class="display table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive">
```

simply delete `table-striped`.

Comment: This works for a jQuery DataTable version 1.10 using Bootstrap 4.0. It was the correct answer for me so I don't know why it was downvoted.

Comment: so difficult to understand some developers :)